# gitignore not working (reason found) using gitextensions in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, git-extensions

I'm using gitextensions in visual studio 2010, and apparently I added a bunch of files to my repository which I didnt want to track. I later edited the gitignore file to try to exclude them, but now I realize that this will not remove the files already added which are now part of the gitignore.

I found this discussion on how to remove the files I don't want to track: [Ignore files that have already been committed to a Git repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/gitignore-file-not-ignoring)

But, I'd like to see if there is a way to do this same thing using gitextensions, instead of the commandline?

Comment: It seems like your question is, essentially, how do I do the equivalent of `git rm --cached` using gitextensions - it doesn't really have anything to do with gitignores.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this in git extensions. Use the command line. It's better and faster anyway. You get bash functionality, command history and many other things you throw out the window when you use an IDE's interface for VCS.

Comment: looks like I'll have to. I'm trying to use git without becoming a guru on it, I get tired of always being the guru ;)

Comment: Adam's right, though: Git has always been a command-line tool, and no one has yet made a GUI that encompasses all of the features, and the things that come closest (EGit) are not too polished yet either. The CLI is the one that's had years of use and lots of effort by lots of people.

Comment: The lack of good IDE or GUI tooling for Git is quite lamentable though. I'm fine with CLI, but I have team mates who aren't.

Comment: the combination of gitk and gitgui will allow you to do everything you do on the command line graphically.